# ACL cache size increase for AEM

Tags: java, aem, acl, crx

I know from the below link that I have to set JVM parameter to increase the cache size.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/cacheentrycollector-cache-size-is-too-small.html

But where exactly should I set this value? In workspace.xml or some where else?

```
-Dorg.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authorization.acl.CachingEntryCollector.maxsize=40000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

1. On `<your cq5 folder>/crx-quickstart/bin`, open `start` (Unix) or `start.bat` (Windows)
2. Search line that have this parameter: `CQ_JVM_OPTS`
3. Add your configurations to the parameter, for example:

   ```
   CQ_JVM_OPTS='-server -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Dorg.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authorization.acl.CachingEntryCollector.maxsize=40000'
   ```
4. Save and use the file to start your CQ5 application.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this

Comment: Just an official link: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/cacheentrycollector-cache-size-is-too-small.html